# JQUERY get content of each table cell with id = xyz

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML table:

```
<table class="xyz">
    [...] 
    <tbody>
        [...]
        <tr>
            [...]
            <td class="id9">some content</td>
            <td class="id39">some content</td>
        </tr>
        [...]
        <tr>
            [...]
            <td class="id9">some content</td>
            <td class="id39">some content</td>
        </tr>
        [...]
    </tbody>
    [...]
```

So I have some cells with ID's and now I want to get the content of all cells with `id=39` for example.

What I tried is to use the each function on all td's and then check the id with `value.attr('id')` and finally check the id with contains.

I'm quite new to jQuery, so what I tried is a mess.

Hope someone has a idea.

Comment: I think you're confusing `id` with `class`. These elements have a **class** that begins with "id", but they have no `id` attribute.

Comment: "class" and "id" are two different things :)  Should be noted that class is what you should be using here though.  The id attribute is required to be unique, so trying to have id="id39" on two elements would not work.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you seem to be confused between `id` and `class`. You are using `class` in your example markup, which is the correct approach, as you cannot have duplicate `id` values in the same document. However, you keep mentioning that you want to select items based on `id`.

The class selector, `.`, will let you select all elements with a specific class. So in your case:

`$(".id39")`

Will select all elements with `class="id39"`. You can then iterate over the set of matched elements with `each` and do whatever you like with the value:

```
$(".id39").each(function() {
    var currentValue = $(this).text();
});
```

If you just want to apply some jQuery method to all selected elements, then you don't need to bother with the `each`. For example, to hide all matched elements:

```
$(".id39").hide(); //Hides all elements with class "id39"
```

Comment: You may want to provide searching context in your samples.  Newbies might not realize the impact otherwise of not including it.  Your global class selector would be a real downer on performance as compared to one given the appropriate context:  `$('table.xyz').find('td.id39')`.  Other than that, +1 for the most complete/pertinent answer. :)

Comment: Yes, agreed. However, I think the addition of the `find` method in your example adds unnecessary complication. I would say `$("td.id39")` would suffice.

Comment: The addition of .find makes that query roughly twice as fast in IE7 and IE8 than without it (http://jsperf.com/table-find-test).  But yeah, it's highly variable by browser as to which one performs the best.  With `getElementByClass` becomming more common, `$('.id39')` will be just as fast/faster than all of them.  In fact in FF6, $('.id39') is almost 6 times faster than what I wrote!  Pretty surprising.  For now...  you just have to make an informed decision based on what browsers your users employ, I guess. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
$("td.id9").each(function(){  
  .... 

 });
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Those aren't ids, they are classes.  You can use the jQuery selector `$("td.id39");` to retrieve the table cell.  IDs are unique while classes can apply to many elements.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Tyler Eaves answer, if you wanted to collect all of the content to a concatenated string, you could simply do...

```
var text = '';
$('td.id9').each(function(i, elem) { text += $(elem).text(); });
```

Furthermore, you could roll it into a re-usable function that takes the ID number as an input parameter...

```
function GetTdContent(id) {
    var text = '';
    $('td.id' + id).each(function(i, elem) { text += $(elem).text(); });
    return text;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarity your example shows tds with the class set to id39 not the id attribute, assuming that this is correct you will want to use something like this:

```
$(".id39").each( function () {
    //do some stuff
});
```

More info on the JQuery each function can be found in the [API Docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/)